# What are the possible calculations for the item sell values?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been reading the PBE about **Cull**.

[image]

Now here's the thing. So far the item provides you 1 extra gold per each minion killed, and for a total of 100 minions, it rewards with an extra 300 amount, which makes it 400 gold reward, which is almost the same amount of money to buy this item.

Now, what if you sell it? How much is it worth selling? Would it be even less or more than the memorable early game item Doran's Blade? (440g buy cost - 176g sell cost)

Succesively I wonder, how does League calculate the sell values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starter items like the Doran's series sell for 40% of their value. Other items sell for ~75% of their value.

I'm pretty sure Cull will fall into the starter items category, making it pretty darn gold efficient.

Specifically, I would guess that Cull sells for 180g. Making its total return 580g.

Edit: As Tim B pointed out, the net income would be 130g. The gross income from the item is 580g.

Comment: Actually the return is 130gp (the profit) since that's the income - the cost.

Comment: Sorry, by return I meant bonus income for receiving the full effect and selling the item. I did not mean to indicate the profit as being 580g.

Comment: Thats 5/6 early game minions. Avarice is 200g for 100 cs + 600g if you sell it. So you get even without the blade's passive gold income.

Comment: @Gnarly404 I think Avarice definitely provides a higher return, but for a starter item, Cull gives you AD at negative cost assuming you fulfill its passive and sell it back. I personally think the item needs more tuning in order to actually be desirable over the Doran series.

Comment: You didn't take into consideration that the bonus is then doubled to +2 per minion after your reach 100. that would increase your return on it the longer you hold it before selling.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Cull doesn't do what you say it does. The passive is removed after you reach 100.

Comment: @nukeforum I misread disables as doubles, you're right.